# Interesting logic to be solved in teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, sqltransaction

[image: Data and question]

In the image the target is top calculate years since last DX.
A year level we want to calculate thw number of years since we have found a DX.
Eg
There was a dx for id 1 in 2014 so in 2015,2016 and 2017 we are populating the value in incremental manner of year.
we find one more DX in 2017 so in the following year we populate 1.
the same cycle beging in next ID

The Idea is to implement this logic in Teradata SQL
Can someone help how this could be done?

Comment: Your `date` certainly does not look like a "date".  Please explain how years are calculated.

Comment: its is in yy,yym,dd
Sorry guys not the best format

Comment: How do you calculate the years, calendar years or actual difference? E.g. when is a year over after 2012-12-13? 2013-12-13 or 2013-01-01?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the largest value for the most recent "DX" value using analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when code = 'DX' then date end) over
           (partition by id
            order by date
            range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
           ) as prev_dx
from t;
```

I have no idea how to convert this to "years".  The date format makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thank you Gordon,
Your solution helped me resolve most of it.
I am not able to achieve one case

That is in Year 2017 there was a DX the present code resets to 0 but it should be counted to 3.
Would there be anything that we could do?#

Comment: What if you drop "and current row" from the window?

Comment: @Fred . . . I think it works, perhaps without the `between`.

Comment: I dropped both between and current row.
Nothing changed.
rows  unbounded preceding --and current row

Comment: @Nirvana . . . I think `range between` does what you want.  I modified the answer.